# show label when hover over image

Tags: html, css

I want to create when the user hover over the image show something like this:
[image]

how can I create like this with HTML and css
thanks, everyone!

Comment: What do you have so far? Please share your HTML and any (relevant) JavaScript code you have.

Comment: nothing..... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can show the text when you hover the container. Set the container to `position:relative` and the text to `position:absolute`.

```css
.container{
  border:1px solid black;
  width:fit-content;
  position:relative;
}
img{
  width:200px;
}
.text{
  display:none;
  color:white;
  background-color:red;
  border-radius:20px;
  padding:5px 10px;
}
.container:hover .text{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/ef/Stack_Overflow_icon.svg/768px-Stack_Overflow_icon.svg.png" alt="">
  <div class="text">Hello</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I keep things simple as you didn't share any of your code.

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="label"></div>
</div>
```

assume container is the background image. your CSS should look like this:

```
.label {
    display: none;
}
.container:hover .label {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work

```js
$("document").ready(function(){
  $("img").hover(function(){
   $("p").toggle();
 });
 });
```

```css
p {
  background-color:gray;
  color:yellow;
  width:80px;
  height:20px;
  border-radius:10px;
  text-align:center;
  top:10px;
  left:10px;
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
  }
  
 img {position:relative;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div>
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b1/VAN_CAT.png/220px-VAN_CAT.png" />
<p>Hello!</p>
</div>
```